# JQuery Mobile dynamically populated collapsable set losing rounded corners

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I thought it might have been something about my code or css, but I can reproduce it in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kegmT/

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div style="padding:20px">
            <div>Here's the problem - this dynamicaly populated collapsable set should have rounded corners:</div>
            <div id="output" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"></div>
            <div>If I use the same content but do not render it dynamically, it is fine:</div>
            <div id="static" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Container 1</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d"></ul>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Container 2</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" start="" id="category-0" end="">
                        <li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(0)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 1</h3></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(1)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 2</h3></a>
                        </li>
                </div>
                <div>Why the difference?</div>
            </div>
</body>

<script>

$('#output').append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h2>Container 1</h2><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d"></ul></div><div data-role="collapsible"><h2>Container 2</h2><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" start="" id="category-0" end=""><li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(0)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 1</h3></a></li><li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(1)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 2</h3></a></li>');

$('#output').trigger('create');

</script>
```

Whenever I run trigger('create') on a collapsable set, it seems to fail to flag the first child and last child needing rounded corners.

Any ideas?  I've run out of ideas, minus manually applying the classes myself after rendering..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2QMk6/

Collapsibles  will have round borders only if they are part of a collapsible set. So when dynamically creating 2 collapsibless you also need to dynamically create a collapsible set. without it jQuery Mobile will create 2 basic collapsibles, it doesn't matter you placed them inside a collapsible set.

### Code:

#### Javascript:

```
$('#output').after('<div id="new-collapsible-set" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"><div data-role="collapsible"><h2>Container 1</h2><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d"></ul></div><div data-role="collapsible"><h2>Container 2</h2><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" start="" id="category-0" end=""><li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(0)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 1</h3></a></li><li><a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(1)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px"><img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "><h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 2</h3></a></li></div></div>');

$('#index').trigger('create');
```

#### HTML :

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div style="padding:20px">
                <div>Here's the problem - this dynamicaly populated collapsable set should have rounded corners:</div>
            </div>
            <div id="output">If I use the same content but do not render it dynamically, it is fine:</div>
            <div id="static" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Container 1</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d"></ul>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Container 2</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" start="" id="category-0" end="">
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(0)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px">
                                <img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "/>
                                <h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 1</h3>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="email_choose_template.selectTemplate(1)" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:62px">
                                <img src="../../images/email_icon.png" style="width:40px; height:42px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px; "/>
                                <h3 style="font-size:12px;">Template 2</h3>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>Why the difference?</div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`data-role=collapsible-set` accepts `refresh` method for dynamically added elements, this way.

```
$('.selector').collapsibleset('refresh');
```

**Note** that `refresh` doesn't work for `data-role=collapsible`.

> **Demo**

**Ref: [Collapsible-set API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/#method-refresh)**

Comment: +1 Better solution then my m8, congrats, I have forgot sollapsible set has a refresh method.

Comment: @Gajotres thanks buddy. using `create` is correct too, you should've kept your answer :)

Comment: @Gajotres Wow, very nice!  I'll make your answer the correct one, though I'll weave in what Omar is saying as well.  Thanks a ton!